# Ionic 2 Deploy Version Number issue

Tags: angular, deployment, ionic2

I'm having an issue with Ionic Deploy in where although my app downloads and installs a new snapshot the version number found in "config.xml" does not change.

After code changes an 'ionic build' and an 'ionic upload' puts a new snapshot to the cloud. When I run a 'deploy.check()' my app recognises there is an update and will happily download and install it showing all updated code. Though I dont know how I will be able to control these updates without having a new version number. 'deploy.info()' doesn't seem to show a reliable version either.

Am I missing a step or something?

Answer (score 0):

My Methods as follows:

Don't rely on just the 'deploy.check()', you should have a database field that you first query, if it says you can download then do the check and download.

Then the version number of your app can never change. Image your user looks on his app and see that he is on version 1.0.20 but then on the Stores the latest version is 1.0.10, confusion galore. So leave the version as is. Instead create a config file in your, that has a property: BUILD_NUMBER make this a constant. Then every time you do an ionic upload, increase this number. Then below the version show the Build Number field. So then you can be on either version 1.0.10 or version 1.0.20 but as long as the build number is the same then they both have the same code base.

Hope this makes sense.